# Meteor/mongo doesnt update collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have this function:

```
 Meteor.setInterval( function () {
  productDate = Products.findOne({isItReady: false});
  console.log(productDate+ 'found something')
    var timeNow = Date();
    var timeNow = timeNow.toString();
    var timeCreated = productDate.createdAt
    var timeCreated = timeCreated.toString();
    var productId = productDate._id;
    productDate = Products.findOne({});

    if (timeCreated <= timeNow) {
        console.log("check")
    Products.update({_id: productId}, {$set: {isItReady: true}})
    }
  }, 5000);
```

All console.log are succesful but my collection doesnt get updated with new value for isItReady. What could be the issue?

Update:

My function now is:

```
 Meteor.setInterval( function () {
    productDate = Products.findOne({});
    var timeNow = Date();
    var timeNow = timeNow.toString();
    var timeCreated = productDate.createdAt;
    var timeCreated = timeCreated.toString();
    var productId = productDate._id;

    if (timeCreated <= timeNow) {
        console.log("check")

    Products.update({_id: productId}, {$set: {isItReady: true}}, function(error, result) {
        console.log(productId)
        if (error){
            console.log(error.reason) //check the error
        } else{
            console.log("File with the id: " + result + " just get update")
        }

    });
    }
  }, 5000);
```

Definition of the Products collection:

```
Products = new Mongo.Collection("products");
```

I get from in my server console:

```
I20150426-19:12:59.818(3)? check
I20150426-19:12:59.820(3)? eXPzq5K6Kam35X27m
I20150426-19:12:59.821(3)? File with the id: 1 just get update
```

But in reality when I check my collection after this update its like this:

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.products.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : "eXPzq5K6Kam35X27m",
    "tooteNimetus" : "2001311",
    "partii" : "23",
    "trummel" : "1",
    "tootmistellimus" : 1,
    "startOfCountdown" : ISODate("2015-04-26T16:11:19.702Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-04-26T16:10:19.702Z"),
    "isItReady" : false,
    "whoCreated" : null
}
```

this isItReady doesn't get updated to `:true` although the function execution is succesful

Comment: Are there any errors in your meteor console?  Why not create a callback in your update statement? http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/update

Comment: Do you use allow/deny or insecure more, and if the first, is allow/deny set up to allow the browser to have permission to update (note: sometimes this is a bad idea)?  `productDate` maybe needs a `var` to avoid being a global, and perhaps corrupted by some other routine.  There is a missing `;` on the first `var timeCreated` line.  It is not obvious to me what the second `productDate = ` is supposed to do.  It is merely a side effect.  Perhaps string comparison isn't the best way to compare timeCreated with timeNow since that means alphabetical order, instead of date order.

Answer (score 1):

If you see that you see all the consoles and also this, `console.log("check")`.

Be sure of this.

Did you have the insecure package installed? run `meteor list` and check if `insecure` and `autopublish` package are or no on the list.

if they are **NOT** on the list, be sure you have the corrects allows rules on the `/server` or `if(Meteor.isServer)`

```
Products.allow({
 update:function(){return true;}
})
```

Now do the following, use a `callback`, like this.

```
Products.update({_id: productId}, {$set: {isItReady: true}},function(error,result){
  if(error){
    console.log(error.reason) //check the error.
   }else{
    console.log("File with the id: " + result + " just get updated")
   }
})
```

Comment: I tried now this callback and I get this:

I20150424-09:45:00.197(3)? eXPzq5K6Kam35X27m //this is from console.log(productId)

I20150424-09:45:00.205(3)? File with the id: 1 just get update //this is the result, what it means?

Still collection doesnt get updated

Comment: No it doesn't get updated, isItReady is false in my collection.

Comment: the code looks ok and the console to, try to run the same update on the browser console `Products.update({_id: "eXPzq5K6Kam35X27m"}, {$set: {isItReady: true}})`

Comment: when I run it in the console, I get this:

Products.update({_id: "eXPzq5K6Kam35X27m"}, {$set: {isItReady: true}})
0

But I have insecure enabled.

I also get this in the console: Exception in setInterval callback: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createdAt' of undefined

Comment: Nevermind the exception, this was due to dublicate function... my mistake.

Now I get only this when trying to update in the console:

Products.update({_id: "eXPzq5K6Kam35X27m"}, {$set: {isItReady: true}})
0

Comment: Another thing I noticed. When I run in mongo console:
db.products.update({"_id": "eXPzq5K6Kam35X27m"}, {$set: {"isItReady": true}})

my isItTrue get set to :true 

but now when my function is invoked, the isItTrue gets set back to false.
I don't have anything in my function that could set the value back to false??

Comment: Update your question and show your declaration of the Products collection. Are you sure that the collection you're looking at on the client is the same collection that you're querying in the mongo console?